# How to make an activity use retrofit get request to load json data when starting?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to get retrofit make a http call when the activity starts, so it loads the data. I also want it to be callable on refresh.

How can I achieve this without using AsyncTask?

Comment: Make the call & load the data in `onCreate` via some `Thread`, `Service`, maybe `Coroutines` if using Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm sorry but I'm using Java. Is there any alternative to coroutine in Java?

Comment: As I said above: `Thread`, `Executors`, `Services`, etc.